# How can I font-lock JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I find the default syntax highlighting for JavaScript and TypeScript to be lacking slightly.

For example, s there a package equivalent to [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) for Emacs? I have tried Emacs [tree-sitter](https://emacs-tree-sitter.github.io) but it seems to overwrite or theme colors.

Comment: You find the highlighting "to be lacking slightly"? How so? That's unclear - too vague, and it encourages opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

`js2-mode` has been my recommendation for a while, though I don’t believe the original author is still maintaining it. There is also a `js3-mode` which I haven’t tried yet; I believe it has some improvements over `js2-mode`.

Comment: Is `js3` maintained? The version from MELPA  is 20160515.1550 and the github [site](https://github.com/tamzinblake/js3-mode) hasn't seen an update in seven years. I tried it, had problems, gave up and went back to the builtin `js.el` just to get things working again. I'll try `js2` at some point...

Comment: Does it need to be maintained? Has Javascript changed much since 2016?

Comment: I guess not, but Emacs certainly has: the problems I had were trying to load the darn thing into Emacs.